# Bastion Server + EC2 Instances

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, bastion

I would to protect my VPC using a bastion. So I add to the bastion only the public keys. But I have some EC2 instances inside my VPC. 
Do I need to add the public both to bastion and EC2 instances?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/securely-connect-to-linux-instances-running-in-a-private-amazon-vpc/

Comment: Once you've logged into the bastion you're on the network. From there you can log into any server in your network using any authentication method you like. If the servers require keys then you'd need them on the bastion.